# When to "wind-your-own" vs "scavenge" a transformer?

Tags: transformer, design, component-selection

I often see answers for one-off designs including the advice, "Just wind a transformer...."  Like it's no big deal.  Did I miss a class in which they handed out a sheet listing the formulas for core size, composition, geometry; wire gauge and insulation; and winding style as a function of voltage, power, frequency, duty cycle, and load application?

But I also frequently see [people scavenging and reverse-engineering the pins on flyback transformers from CRTs](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/162207/39511).

So I'm deducing that there's an envelope inside which one realistically hand-winds a custom transformer, and outside of which it would be difficult/wasteful/dangerous to do so.  What are the parameters of that envelope, and why?

Comment: For mains I'd buy an off the shelf one, for a small smps I'd wind my own (*after* having a good read of the datasheet for tthe core), for a large smps (you still can't get one off the shelf but...) I'd probably get a professional company to make one for me, coilcraaft even have smps transformer *kits*, pick the ratio you want, stay within the power limits and go, a neat idea I've not seen often

Answer (score 3):

Yes you did!
NAB=Vt for any core saturated topology including all 50/60 Hz transformers, and
Vrms=4.44fNAB for sinusodial waves. You can assume 1 for B for laminated iron core or perhaps 0.8 for a conservateive design (you are trading no-load losses for copper losses here).

Wire gauge is normal thermal heating for all low frequency transformers or rule of thumb 4 A/mm^2 for you most conservative and very long life time even at high ambient temperatures up to about 10 A/mm^2 for very small with good cooling and only ambient temperature.

If you have pulse applications, core saturation equations are the same but wire gauge can be heavily compromised.

Answer (score 3):

Cost (money and time), and availability.

There are several "standard" transformers that can be bought ready, for example it is likely that you can buy 1:1 with different cores and wire gauges. If you need an uncommon ratio, multiple secondaries, off-center taps or a combination of these, then you find yourself in the "long tail" of the market, where specialist firms will gladly build transformers for you...for a price.

At this point, it usually becomes cheaper and faster to build your own, especially for one-off projects. The formulas can be found in the relevant literature or on the Internet, and I'm sure these are mentioned more than casually in EE courses as well.